# Gulp Bower error on default task with Libsass & Susy

Tags: gulp, bower, susy, gulp-sass

When I run the `gulp` task (default) for the first time, the `sass` task gives an error on a Bower package. More specifically on [Susy](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/).

**The error:**

```
Plumber found unhandled error:
   Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
   Message:
      file to import not found or unreadable: su/utilities
   Current dir: /Users/Jeroen/sites/gulp/bower_components/susy/sass/susy/
```

The Susy bower package is being installed successfully with [gulp-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower), taking its information from my bower.json file. However, when the default task gets to the `sass` task, it can't find Susy.

**style.scss**

```
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";
```

This only occurs when I run `gulp` for the first time. The `watch` task doesn't stop/breaks after this error, and keeps working after. (I can compile sass without a problem).

But it looks abit messy, any ideas on how I can prevent this?

You can see my entire gulpfile.js here:
https://gist.github.com/JeroenDelbrk/798d646af5cc2ad78da0

Tips on how I can improve my gulpfile, unrelated to this question, are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
gulp.task('default', ['bower', 'sass', 'scripts', 'imagemin', 'iconfont', 'watch']);
```

All of the tasks are getting executed in parallel. Which is fine if you don't have any dependencies. However, judging from your explanations, a successful run of `sass` is strongly dependent on a successful execution of `bower`. At the time you run `sass`, `bower` might not be finished, thus not providing the files you need.

To solve that in Gulp 3.*, you need to wire your dependencies right. I'd suggest the following:

```
// Define plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins');
    $ = gulpLoadPlugins();

gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return $.bower()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./bower_components'))
});

// Sass compile + prefix task
gulp.task('sass', ['bower'], function(){
  ...
});



// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'scripts', 'imagemin', 'iconfont']);

// Watch Task
gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function(){
  gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('originals/*', ['imagemin']);
  gulp.watch('icons/*.svg', ['iconfont']);
});
```

And ruf `gulp watch`. This will execute all tasks which can be run in parallel at the same time, but bower will be executed before sass. One problem you might face: Running `bower` everytime you'll execute `sass`. That's why we will use `gulp-changed` to prevent reruns.

```
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return $.bower()
    .pipe(changed('./bower_components'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./bower_components'))
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, adding the task dependencies fixes the problem. However, when I add  `gulp-changed` in the mix, it gives another error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'mtime' of null`. I did not know about this plugin, and it looks quite useful. So I'm gonna see if you can get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This might be why `gulp-changed` is not working: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed/issues/27

Comment: Ah, fair enough. `gulp-newer` might be also one plugin you might be interested in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer